# BitCode and unexported_symbols_list cannot be used together?

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, bitcode

For an iOS Framework, I'd like to be able to hide the symbols inside of it, in order to prevent collisions when the framework, and the application that uses the framework, include different versions of the same 3rd party library.

Until now this has been possible by specifying `-unexported_symbols_list` in the options.

However, in Xcode 7 Beta 5, the following error message...

```
-unexported_symbols_list and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode 
setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
```

...occurs when trying to compile the BitCode version of the framework.

So, I have three (3) questions:

1) Is there a straightforward way to hide your symbols when compiling BitCode?

2) If not, is there anything else that can be done to keep the Framework's 3rd-party libraries from colliding with the Application's 3rd-party libraries when they are the same lib, but different versions?

3) *Why* can't `-unexported_symbols_list` and `-bitcode_bundle` be used together?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (since I am also looking for the complete answer)

When using `-exported_symbols_list` or `-unexported_symbols_list` in the options, the various functions symbols are turned into local symbols.

For some reason, the linker is unable use bitcode option with local symbols.

Hence the two cannot be used together.

Also note, `strip` keyword which is used for symbol hiding can hide global symbols but the library has to be dynamic. 
This is an option I haven't explored completely yet. If a dynamic library works for you, then you should explore it.

If this helps someone get a different perspective as to how to resolve this issue, that would be awesome.